# Выбор нового ЯП для обучения

Tags: android, ios, мобильная-разработка

Возник вопрос, по выбору нового ЯП для изучения.

Ближе к сути, я работаю с PHP уже года 3-4 и внезапно захотелось "новых ощущений" - мобильной разработки.

Я ознакомлен с Python и C#. Эти языки вроде бы и решают задачу удовлетворения моего интереса, но они мне как-то не "зашли".

В Python мне не нравится отсутствие строгой типизации и модификаторов доступа.

C# мне очень понравился, но я не переношу Windows. А, как я понял, без Windows и Visual Studio C# не раскроет весь свой потенциал.
+ я так понимаю, что C# практически не юзается в мобильной разработке.

Может быть вы сможете мне подсказать ЯП, который совмещает в себе строгость и скорость C# и универсальность и простоту (вот это не обязательно) Python.

P.S.
Вроде как есть Java, но может быть есть что-то поновее, поинтересней.

Comment: kotlin без лишних комментариев

Comment: спасибо за ответ!
А он разве катит и под ios?

Comment: Для каждой мобильной платформы существует язык, который наиболее полно раскрывает ее возможности. Поэтому одним языком обойтись будет трудно. Для ios есть swift

Comment: Понял, спасибо. Попробую посмотреть котлин.

Comment: В Python типизация как раз строгая, просто при этом динамическая и утиная.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для мобильной разработки в 2019 году есть два современных языка:

1. Kotlin для разработки под Android
2. Swift для разработки под iOS (в скором времени в целом под все устройства Apple, т.к. недавно появилась технология SwiftUI).

Могу порекомендовать сайт swiftbook.ru. Я iOS разработчик и начинал свой путь именно с этого сайта. На нем много интересных курсов по обучению разработке под iOS на Swift.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!
Я так понимаю, без макбука туда смысла нету лезть?

Comment: Да. Из бюджетных вариантов можно купить подержанный Macbook Air, главное чтобы он обновлялся до последней версии MacOS(желательно не старей 2015 года, чтобы попользоваться хотя бы 2-3 года)